# How would I calculate interest daily in SQL Server 2008 using a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduling

Basically, I want to take my current Account.Balance and calculate interest once daily, based on the rate defined as Account.InterestRate.

I have table "Account" with (relevant columns) "InterestRate" and "Balance". I need to have a job run nightly (@ midnight?) that calculates the Balance field based on the current value of Balance and the InterestRate.

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: So an oversight on my part has created an issue. I'm unable to do the UPDATE statement on the Balance column, as Balance is a calculated column. I need to do something like INSERT INTO [Transaction] the columns "Account_Id", "Amount", "DateTime", "Comment", and "Trans_Type_Id" for each account...

Comment: Is interest per day or per year? Flat or APR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a strong way to do it.

Basically, since I can't edit Account.Balance directly, I'm creating a new Transaction record to credit(or debit, if the balance is negative) the interest, which is defined by Account.Balance * Account.Interest_Rate. The calculation I'm using is simple and works well for a very simple form of interest calculations. If, however, I wanted to calculate this once per day for, for instance, 12.99% APR, the calculation would be a little different. Here are examples of both.

To calculate basic daily interest, set up a job to run nightly @ 12:00:00 AM, running the following:

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction] ([Account_Id], [Amount], [Trans_Type_Id], [DateTime], [Comment])
SELECT Account_Id, Balance * Interest_Rate, 101, GETDATE(), 'Interest' FROM Account WHERE Interest_Rate <> 0.0000
```

This will create a new transaction once daily for each customer whose Account.Interest_Rate is not 0.0000%.

To calculate APR, say for accounts of CreditCard type, set up a job to run monthly on the 1st of each month @ 12:00:00 AM, running the following:

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction] ([Account_Id], [Amount], [Trans_Type_Id], [DateTime], [Comment])
SELECT Account_Id, ((Interest_Rate/12) * Balance), 101, GETDATE(), 'Interest' FROM Account WHERE Interest_Rate <> 0.0000 AND Account_Type = 103
```

(where Account_Type = 103 is "CreditCard")

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [procedure](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/storedprocedure.htm) or just straight sql and add the logic for calculating the balance(should be an update with recalculating the balance) something like this -

```
Update Account Set balance=balance*interest
```

and then use sql server [agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to create jobs(your sql) to be executed nightly(**Note**: SQL Server agent won't work on Express editions...in that case you might need to use scheduled tasks on your server and run a batch(.bat) files.)

Comment: I imagine Balance should be updated to Balance+(Balance*InterestRate)

How would I go about having the procedure spool through all accounts and update balances as appropriate?

Comment: Ya maybe...I am not sure how your database works..you might need to figure out a query that updates all accounts and you dont need a procedure unless..you want to pass something...just create a job and add your logic...

Comment: Would "UPDATE Account SET Balance = Balance + (Balance * Interest_Rate)" update all instances of Account.Balance?

Comment: Yea..it will do it it for all entries in the table.